# Sum of a sequence and convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given the following $\frac{1}{2^2}+
\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{2^4}+...+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{3^3}+...+$

Can this be symbolized as:
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}2^{-n}+(n+1)^{-n}$$

and if so, are the following values for $S_{n}$ correct?

$$S_n= \begin{cases}
\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{n},\\
-\frac{1}{4}\\
\end{cases}$$

The formula for $S_n$ is $$S_n=\frac{n}{2}(a_1+a_n)$$

Comment: I don't understand your symbolisation, my dear puss!

Comment: The values for $S_n$ do not appear to be correct.  How did you arrive at them?  In the primary sum, does it continue as $\frac 1{4^2}+\frac 1{4^3}+\dots$? If so, the expression using $n$ for the sum does not seem to relate correctly.

Comment: It is rather a double summation : first the negative powers of $2$ than those of $3$, then $4$ etc. What is the sum $$\sum_{2}^{\infty}m^{-n}$$ The sum you’re examining is $$\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}m^{-n}$$

Comment: @abiessu
thank you, i've only just learned series.  I used $a_1 = 2^{-n}$ and $a_n = (n+1)^{-n}$ substituted into $S_n$.

and yes, it continues such that every power is an integer greater than the first power  and greater than 1.  The series is the sum of the reciprocals.

Comment: $a_1=2^{-n}$ is strange because the left side doesn't depends on $n$ while the right side does. Perhaps $a_1=\sum_{k=2}^\infty 2^{-k}$ then $a_n=\sum_{k=2}^\infty (n+1)^{-k}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me follow up on my comment.

We start with the inner sum, a geometric series

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty{1\over m^n}={1\over m^2}{1\over 1-{1\over m}}={1\over m^2-m}$$

Now we décompose the rational fraction

$${1\over m(m-1)}={1\over m-1}-{1\over m}$$

And so the double sum is just telescoping

$$\sum_{m=2}^\infty\sum_{n=2}^\infty{1\over m^n}=\sum_{m=2}^\infty \left({1\over m-1}-{1\over m}\right)=1$$

Answer (score 2):

Your expression seems uncorrect, we can use a double series

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac1{n^k}\right)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac1n}-1-\frac1{n}\right)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n-1)} =\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac1{n-1}-\frac1{n}\right)=1$$

Comment: You should have $${1\over 1-{1\over n}}-1-{1\over n}={1\over n(n-1)}$$ inside the sum

Comment: Yes of course! I need to subtract $1/n $ and not $1/n^2$. Thanks I fix it.